# jQuery Validation on Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that I need to validate on my page. The form looks like this:
[image]

I am trying to figure out the best way to make sure that if one piece of information in the row is filled out ; then the whole row needs to be filled out.

As you can see in the example, row 3 has the costs filled out but no title. Row 4 has the title but no costs. I need to throw errors on these types of things.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this to make sure if one piece of data is there (in any of the 3 editable fields) then the whole row needs data.

Thanks for any input

Comment: Are the number of records dynamic or is it limited to 6?

Comment: Limited to 6 right now but trying to make it flexible in case i need to add more

Comment: Are you willing to use basic jQuery plugins or are you limited to pure jQuery and JavaScript?

Comment: I could use a plugin if there was an easy way to do the row validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
$("#mytable tr").each(function() {
    var anySet = false, allSet = true;
    $(this).find("td input").each(function() {
        var somethingInCell = $(this).val().trim() !== '';
        anySet |= somethingInCell;
        allSet &= somethingInCell;
    });
    if (anySet && !allSet) {
        // there is missing information
    }
});
```

UPDATE

```
    $("#mytable").on("input", "input", function(){
        var anySet = false,
            $cells = $(this).closest("tr").find("td input");
        $cells.each(function() {
            var somethingInCell = $(this).val().trim() !== '';
            anySet |= somethingInCell;
        });
        $cells.removeClass("has-error");
        if (anySet) {
            $cells.each(function() {
                if ($(this).val().trim() === '') {
                    $(this).addClass("has-error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: This seems possible but my question would be; Where would I add validation for like displaying an error message? I would like to add the class 'has-error' to the fields that are missing.

Comment: I would do this in the input event of all the input elements

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually do this. I am not going to write whole code for you but it will be something like this.

```
//on hove of each td
        $('#tableID tr td').hover(function(){
//loop each its sibling
           $(this).siblings().each(function(
//if any sibling is empty return false 
                 if($(this).val().trim() == '')
                 {
                   return false;
                 }
           ));
//else return true
                   return true;
        });
```